# Adding numbers from different input files

Tags: bash

I have files with this format

```
A yield 123
B yield 345
C yield 165
```

and in another similarly

```
A yield 456
B yield 5675
C yield 34534
```

How can I add the number columns from all input files in bash?

```
A yield 123+456
```

But A,B,C are bit complex strings which might include symbols etc but there is always a "yield" word inbetween these and the numbers

thanks

Alex

Comment: Are you adding the numbers or just printing the numbers with `+` in between? If it's the former, you probably should put `A yield 579` as your desired output.

Answer (score 3):

This is a good problem for `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}{print a[$1]"+"$NF}' file1 file2
```

Slightly more robust:

```
awk -F' yield ' '{a[$1]=($1 in a)?a[$1]"+"$2:$2}END{for(i in a)print i" yield "a[i]}' file1 file2
```

or

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=" yield "}{a[$1]=($1 in a)?a[$1]"+"$2:$2}END{for(i in a)print i,a[i]}' file1 file2
```

If you don't really need the +, you might be able to use `join`:

```
join -11 -21 -o1.1,1.2,1.3,2.3 file1 file2
```

This is a bit simpler but more fragile (and needs the files to be sorted; you can replace `file1` with `<(sort file1)` and the same for 2, if needed).

Answer (score 1):

If you are printing the numbers with `+` in between, then you can go with any one of [Kevin's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17125361/970195) answer.

However, if you wish to truly `add` them then the following should work:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1$2]=$3;next}{$NF=$NF+a[$1$2]}1' file1 file2
```

Answer (score 0):

A 99% pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) solution (the remaining 1% is a `cat`). Uses associative arrays:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A a;

while read -r n y b; do
    [[ $y = yield ]] && a[$n]+=${a[$n]:++}$b
done < <(cat file1 file2)

for i in "${!a[@]}"; do
    echo "$i yield ${a[$i]}"
done
```

It will get slow if you have large files. In that case, use the `awk` methods given in the other answers.

If a line doesn't contain the word `yield` in second position, it is silently ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (if it helps) ... simple use of paste and awk

**Input1.txt**

```
A yield 123
B yield 345
C yield 165
```

**Input2.txt**

```
A yield 456
B yield 5675
C yield 34534
```

**Code**

1. If you wish the add the numbers

   paste -d ' ' Input1.txt Input2.txt | awk -F " " '{print $1 " " $2 " " $3+$6}'
2. If you wish to just print '+' sign in between the numbers

   paste -d ' ' Input1.txt Input2.txt | awk -F " " '{print $1 " " $2 " " $3"+"$6}'